# Django - redirect to a view after edit

Tags: python, django, redirect, post

I have a view that allows me to edit/update a post. The post is the result of filling out a form. This is similar I'm guessing to redirecting to a CMS post after editing.  Here's the post view:

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
   model = Product
   form_class = ProductForm
   template_name = 'edit_product.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      self.object.save()
      return redirect ('products')

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

After updating the details in the form it redirects to the 'product' page, whereas I want to redirect to the item just edited.  The URL for the items is:

```
url(r'^([0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
```

Each post is then a number in the url, such as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/13/`.  I can redirect to the previous page, but takes me back to the edit view, whereas, I want to go back to the actual post view, showing the edit.  Hopefully this isn't clear as mud.

I get the sense I need to grap the orginating url, then use it once the form is updated so I'm researching that right now.  Any guidance gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It redirects to the products page because that is what you explicitly told it to do in `form_valid`. If you want to redirect to the detail page, then do that:

```
return redirect('detail', self.object.pk)
```

Comment: Thank you - I knew the redirect in place was going to the products, it was a placeholder while I found out how to do it the right way.  You answer worked, and I very much appreciate the help!